# Какие механизмы безопасности объединяют алгоритмы консенсуса?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

Какие механизмы безопасности используются в алгоритмах консенсуса? Я читал информацию про мультиподпись, кольцевую, групповую и тд, но не было информации нигде, какая подпись в каком алгоритме консенсуса используется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подпись сама по себе в механизмах консенсуса не используется - она только подтверждает авторство "заявителя". Соответственно, это может быть подпись под блоком, подтверждение транзакции или блока и так далее. Сам механизм консенсуса строится на либо на основе получения явного подтверждения блока/транзакции от определенного числа участников (BFT-консенсусы: Ripple, Hyperledger Fablic) либо на основе неявного подтверждения через "продление" той или иной конкурирующей ветви цепочки (PoW, PoS: Bitcoin, Ethereum). В приватных сетях достаточно широко используются CFT-консенсусы, обеспечивающие устойчивость к отказу (например, Raft в Quorum) - там вообще просто периодически из числа действующих выбирается Мастер-узел, блоки которого и считаются валидными.

Comment: Ну то есть, что следует считать механизмом безопасности алгоритма консенсуса? То есть, что применяется в алгоритмах общего, с помощью чего достигается безопасность того или иного алгоритма консенсуса?

Comment: То есть, я до конца понять не могу, алгоритмы консесуса - это только лишь правила, по которым добавляются блоки, а для каждого проекта механизмы вроде мультиподпись и тд и тп - они разные, или есть общие какие-то механизмы типа мультиподпись/хэш функция хамелеона используется для всего PoW например. Научную работу пишу просто, и небольшое непонимание есть с моей стороны в этом месте

Comment: Да, по сути алгоритм консенсуса - это правила по которым добавляются блоки (или транзакции). Подпись - это средство аутентификации участника процесса консенсуса. Скажем, если добавление блока требует подтверждения 2 из 3 генерирующих узлов - можно назвать это мульти-подписью, но по сути это вариант BFT-консенсуса. Безопасность алгоритма консенсуса определяется соответствием его параметрам эксплуатации сети и предполагаемой модели угроз.

Comment: Последний вопрос. Всякое хэширование и шифрование данных так же относится к тому, что является дополнением к конкретному проекту, то есть какой именно алгоритм был использован - зависит только от проекта и не существует общего алгоритма хэширования/шифрования чего-либо для всех проектов, основанных на одном алгоритме консенсуса?

Comment: Да, в принципе, любой блокчейн может использовать свои собственные алгоритмы хеширования/подписи не влияя на используемые алгоритмы консенсуса. Хотя технически они часто совпадают - sha3, например. Например, при разработке российского сертифицированного блокчейна Мастерчейн, основанного на Ethereum, производился переход на ГОСТ-криптографию. У Hyperledger Fabric есть соответствующий программный интерфейс для подключения любой криптографии и Блокчейн-лаборатория Сбера использовала его также для перехода на ГОСТ-криптографию.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо вам огромное!)